# SQL - Select rows after reaching minimum value/threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using Sql Server Mgmt Studio. My data set is as below.

```
ID   Days   Value   Threshold
A    1      10      30
A    2      20      30
A    3      34      30
A    4      25      30
A    5      20      30
B    1      5       15
B    2      10      15
B    3      12      15
B    4      17      15
B    5      20      15
```

I want to run a query so only rows after the threshold has been reached are selected for each ID. Also, I want to create a new days column starting at 1 from where the rows are selected. The expected output for the above dataset will look like

```
ID   Days   Value   Threshold   NewDayColumn
A    3      34      30              1
A    4      25      30              2
A    5      20      30              3
B    4      17      15              1
B    5      20      15              2
```

It doesn't matter if the data goes below the threshold for the latter rows, I want to take the first row when threshold is crossed as 1 and continue counting rows for the ID.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by days) as newDayColumn
from (select t.*,
             min(case when value > threshold then days end) over (partition by id) as threshold_days
      from t
     ) t
where days >= threshold_days;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is partially helpful. :) I think I can figure out row number after this.

Comment: @NeilAk . . . I had missed the `row_number()` part when I read the question (the more interesting part is picking the rows).  But I did put it in.